# NodeJS refer to another URL

Tags: node.js, url, cross-domain

I need to hide reference to another domain from my website. Basically, if someone asks for some file from my web site like so:

http://www.mydomain.com/file/12345

it should go to amazon s3, get it and give back. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to act as a proxy for external files.